# Can not test app directly to device with Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

for a client I wanted to test a Cordova app directly on his android device with `cordova run android` but I get a `No emulator images (avds) found...` error.

I can access the device via `adb shell` and can see it under `adb devices`, but strangely the last command shows the following:

```
List of devices attached 
0000000000000000 device
```

I have not seen this device ID before. Does anyone have a clou if that could cause the Cordova error and a way on how to resolve this? The device is a rk3188.

Thanks in advance

---

Comment: sounds like you device isn't installed properly. If you are on linux, [set up the device drivers](http://esausilva.com/2010/05/13/setting-up-adbusb-drivers-for-android-devices-in-linux-ubuntu/)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am developing under OS X. 

The guide for setting up the device drivers at http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html says `If you're developing on Mac OS X, it just works. Skip this step.`...

I am wondering if it might be possible that this device's vendor is not included in the OS X device drivers and if I could add it somewhere similar as in the linux tutorial. From another board I know the manufacturer's vendor ID is `2207`. Does anybody know where to add this under OS X?

Comment: Okay, added the vendor ID in `adb_usb.ini` but still the same... so I looked up in the system profiler what is connected to the USB ports and there the device actually shows up with a serial of `0000000000000000`... Don't know what to do with this information ... Does anybody have any other idea?